# Calculation of Elliptic Functions at Extreme Values of Eccentricity

Tags: elliptic-functions

The scenario of transverse oscillations of a mass in centre of an elastic string yields an oscillator with a restoring force that is purely cubic ... or a potential well that is quartic. The solution of the transverse motion as a function of time is the Jocobi elliptic function $\operatorname{sn}$ with eccentricity $k=i \therefore k^2=-1$. I wondered what method of computation can still be used at this value of $k$ - and that is infact *the* question.

In the method of *Neville theta functions*, the *nome*

$$q=\exp(-\pi K^\prime/K)$$

is required; but now, since the complementary eccentricity-squared $k^{\prime 2}=1-k^2=2$ we will have a complex

$$K^\prime=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-2x^2)(1-x^2)}} .$$

I should expect that $sn(\omega t)$ would be a quite reasonable real-valued function of $\omega t$, as the solution (with all the scalings taking out) is simply the inverse of

$$\int_0^x\frac{d\upsilon}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} ,$$

which would basically be a $\sin$ curve a bit 'fattened-out'. But do the imaginary parts cancel-out in the expansion the expansions comprised in a Neville's theta function rendering of it? And also, if it be rendered as a Taylor series instead, will this series converge? It is generally said that a condition for convergence is $|k|<1$ ... and if it *does* converge it is likely that it will be very slowly ... and calculating an arbitrary number of coefficients of the series for $sn$ is *not* a trivial matter (have you ever seen the recipe for them!!?).

In practice, people are not particularly interested in calculating the trajectory of a quartic oscillator - they generally want just to 'short-circuit' straight to the energy-levels, & that kind of thing ... *and* furthermore, they might adduce that it has already been done once & forall *anyway*. But! ... I always want to be able to do things like that *myself* - I supppose it is a bit of a *vice* that I have!

So I wonder at what sort of values of $k$ there is a *transition* from the use of these elementary methods that you might well find in old treatises to the *slick algorithms* that I've no doubt the great computer algebra packages have on board. And there are subquestions *implied* in the main one, such as "what is the rate of growth, *wrt* index, of the sum of the coefficients of the polynomials in k^2 that constitute the numerators of the coefficients of the Taylor series for $\operatorname{sn}$?". It doesn't *appear*, from my perusals of the literature anyway, that *this* question, for instance, is much-addressed.

The inspiration for this post further back was actually materials with *negative thermal expansion coefficients*: some of them do not readily evince the precise mechanism whereby they have this property; but in a notable one of them - *scandium trifloride* - it is that the atoms are arranged in such a way that a flouride ion, undergoing transverse quartic oscillations between two scandium ions tends to draw the scandium ions closer together ... which I found really neat!

I am also led to wonder what physicalities $k^2<-1$ might have: I noticed that -1 is a sort of *watershed* beyond which $\operatorname{sn}$ begins to acquire a *dent* (not *kink*, as I said at first, which maybe implies a *discontinuity* of gradient) - which is to say, being more precise, its gradient actually *increases* just after a zero, before levelling-off to turn back. The uttermost extreme of this would be $k^2\rightarrow-\infty$ whereat (provided our scale of observation decrease in proportion with $|k^2|$) it morphs into a $\operatorname{sech}$ function ... if it still be taken as the inverse of the elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: What exactly is your question? To calcuate $sn()$? All the main computer algebra systems can do that for $k=i$.

Comment: I've no doubt a _computer algebra_ system can dispense it as a function. But the issue here is the efficacy of the elementary methods for doing the calculation. As they appear to be a bit _stretched_ on the face of it. I'm interested in whether an expansion in terms of Neville theta functions is valid for _k=i_, & how many terms of the taylor series would have to be computed - that kind of thing - & indeed whether some more _potent_ algorithm is not _wheeled_ out in practice by such as, say _a computer algebra package_, when $|k|$ aporoaches 1. I can't help _needing to know_ what the machinery

Comment: Have you looked at [DLMF 22.20](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.20) or Abramowitz and Stegun?

Comment: I'm familiar with the use of AGM for computing elliptic _integrals_. The use of it for computing elliptic _functions_ is something I was hitherto unacquainted with. I was also unacquainted until very recently with the elementary scenario by which a true _quartic oscillator_ can come-to-be - it's somehow escaped my attention all this time - and it was _that_ that sparked my renewed interest in elliptic functions. Thank-you for directing me to that NIST site, anyway. I expect I shall visit it again.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it now: that the solution is (using *traditional* notation for elliptic integrals/functions - ie that the parameter is $k$, **not** $k^2$)

$$\operatorname{sn}(z,ik)$$$$=\frac{k\operatorname{sn}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{k^2}+1}z, \frac{k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+k^2\operatorname{cn^2}(\sqrt{\frac{1}{k^2}+1}}z, \frac{k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}})} ,$$

which for $k=1$ gives

$$\operatorname{sn}(z,i)$$$$=\frac{\operatorname{sn}\left(\sqrt{2}z, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\operatorname{cn}^2(\sqrt{2}}z, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})} ,$$

$$\operatorname{sn}(z,i)$$$$=\frac{\operatorname{sn}\left(\sqrt{2}z, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2-\operatorname{sn^2}(\sqrt{2}}z, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})} .$$

I have also seen

$$\operatorname{sn}(z,i)$$$$=\operatorname{cn}\left(K\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\sqrt{2}z, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) ,$$

but I do not know exactly from what transformations & identities this is obtained. I have also read that this function has been given a special place amongst the *canon* of functions (similarly to how $\operatorname{gd}x\equiv\operatorname{ln}\operatorname{tan}(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})$ sometimes is), being called *sinus lemniscatus* or $\operatorname{sl}$; and is, as a function of time, the *distance from the origin* of a point moving with unit speed along a lemniscate.

Also, for the purpse of *dedimensionalising* the problem: if we set $q$ the force-constant (force per (unit length)$^3$), & $m$ mass, & $v_0$ the speed at zero displacement, then

$$\Upsilon=\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{2m}{q}}}$$

has dimensions $\sqrt{LT}$; & the characteristic length is $$\Upsilon\sqrt{v_0}$$ & the characteristic time is $$\frac{\Upsilon}{\sqrt{v_0}} .$$

I've also found out that the Taylor series for $\operatorname{sn}$ is divergent at unit argumentsize, which means that the sum of the coefficients must increase at least *factorially* - that being a watershed - a series being convegent *at* unit-argument when the factorial of the numerator is *retarded* by more than 1 with respect to that of the denominator, and convergent if it is retarded by *exactly* 1 or aligned or atall advanced; and the series convergent at unit argument if the numerator is atall *subfactorial*.

It's also fascinating that whereas the solution of the *quartic* oscillator problem can be expressed as the distance-from-origin of a point moving with unit speed along a lemniscate $r=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$, the solution for an ordinary *quadratic* oscillator can likewise be expressed as the distance-from-origin of a point moving with unit speed along a *fattened* 'lemniscate' $r=\cos\theta$ ... or two circles just fitting within the unit circle.

I can't offhand think of how a *hektic* oscillator might simply physically be realised.